# Best solution for hinges and pistons in Blender + Unity?

Tags: rigging, bones, unity

I am looking for the best process in exporting assets to Unity which have interacting hinges and pistons, such as the image below.

I am assuming that weight painting won't work in this case, and that some parameters (such as constraints) don't work in the export (and that the programmer doesn't want sub-meshes), hence my question.

In other words, the piston and hinges are supposed to move with the bouncing wheel while staying rigid.

[image]

Comment: You have only 2 options: weight the parts to bones or keep them separate objects. What ever works better for you in Unity. You will be setting the relationships (constraints) there for your parts, unless you will import animations and drive it through those inside unity.

Comment: Animation as single object or multi-object export with Unity constraints / vehicle system are both technically possible. You should discuss rigging options with your programmer as he will have to make it seem like the movement matches the vehicle moving on terrain (I assume).